# DB2 - How do I run multiple anonymous SQL blocks one after another?

Tags: sql, db2

1. Can I run multiple blocks (BEGIN ... END) using the semi-colon (;) after END?
2. If I am using the same variables in all the blocks, Do I have to declare variables in each block or just the first one?

Comment: You need to use a statement terminator other than semi-colon. Most people use `@`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which program runs the blocks, and your toolset.

This answer is relevant for Db2 command line processor (Db2 CLP).  It may also be relevant for GUI tools that let you execute multiple blocks and allow alternative statement delimiters.

For the Db2-CLP, you can run multiple anonymous blocks  in a script in series (one after the other) provided that you use an alternative statement delimiter. This lets the Db2-command-processor (if that is what runs your script) distinguish between statements inside-the-block  as distinct from the end of the block and the start of the next block. (The BEGIN and END by themselves are not enough).

Example script:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
begin
  statement1;
  statement2; -- etc.
end@

begin
  statement3;
  statement4;
end@
```

If you want to share variables between the blocks then it is best to use GLOBAL variables, otherwise scoping rules will prevent it.  If you have a lot of global variables that can be messy for restarts and cleanups and debugging. Consider using session tables instead (declared global temporary tables ..with replace).  Also consider the structure of your code from the long term maintenance viewpoint, if the code is likely to run for some years.